# How do I access reference member variable from derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, reference

When I am printing reference member variable from derived class it is showing error. But from main class it is showing proper result. 
Please let me know how can I get reference member in derived class.

Thanks

I have sample code as follow:

```
class sample {
    int a;
    public:
    sample(int a_): a(a_){}
    int geta(){ return a; }
};

class base {
protected:
    const int& i;
    const sample& a;
public:
    base(int i_, sample a_):i(i_), a(a_){}
    const int& geti(){ return i; };
    sample getsample(){ return a; };
    virtual void samplefunction() = 0;
};

class derived : public base {
public:
    const int& jt;
    derived(int i, sample a, int jt_): base(i,a), jt(jt_){}
    void samplefunction() { 
        cout<< "geti from derived. " << geti() << endl;
    };
};

int main()
{
    sample ob(20);
    derived *bob = new derived(50, ob, 2002);
    // bob->samplefunction();
    cout << "geti from main. " << bob->geti() << endl;
    bob->samplefunction();

    // cout << "bob inside samplefunction";
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting output as follow:
geti from main. 50
geti from derived. 13307456

from the sample function where I am calling geti must print 50, not a random value. Please suggest me solution.

Comment: What `base::i` refers to? To a temporary object? And why it's a const reference and not just an integer value?

Comment: Change the type of `base::i` to a regular `int`, not a `int&`. You stored a reference to stack memory that changed under you.

Comment: A reference member is almost always the wrong idea, and a member that is a reference to a constructor parameter always is.

Comment: Actually i am using sharedptr to create all the object. Even sample object which is declared in base class is created with shared_ptr.
But when I first created object for sample and then supplied these object to derived class object, it is getting crashed when it is trying to exit from main as it looks like first derived is deleting all the count for sample object, so when sample object is trying to exit it is showing error. p

Comment: @jigarbhanushali If you have a problem you should share code that accurately reflects that problem. Who knows if the code above has the same problem as your real code. It's very common for people to be completely wrong about the cause of their problem, for instance the problem above has nothing at all to do with derived classes. So post your real code, not made up code which you think has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

So in this code

```
base(int i_, sample a_):i(i_), a(a_){}
```

`i_` exists only in the `base` constructor. But your reference to it `i` exists as long as the `base` object exists. This is the fundamental problem, your reference exists for longer than the object it is referring to exists. This is why you see a 'random' number. And note you have exactly the same problem with `a_` and `a`. The only way to make this work is to make the parameters to your constructor be references as well. Like this

```
base(const int& i_, sample a_):i(i_), a(a_){}
```

and this

```
derived(const int& i, sample a, int jt_): base(i,a), jt(jt_){}
```

and in `main`

```
int fifty = 50;
sample ob(20);
derived *bob = new derived(fifty, ob, 2002);
```

Now all your references refer to `fifty` which exists for as long as `main` does. So you avoid the problem.

Hopefully that explains the problem, but as has already been said in the comments above putting references into class is almost always a bad idea precisely because of the lifetime issue. Generally speaking classes should take copies of the objects used to construct them, and if copies are too expensive then use *move constructors* to move instead of copy.

Comment: I don't think OP wanted const references in the first place. Better replace all of them with instances.